# Flowdroid's paper in PLDI'14

Tags: algorithm, static-analysis

I recently read the paper about Flowdroid, but I got very confused with the algorithm of on-demand alias analysis.

When n is assignment in line 14, why construct *d3* replacing *rhs* by *lhs* in d2, not add *lhs* in *d2* to constuct *d3*?

[image: Forward on-demand analysis algorithm]

Comment: could you give a reference to the whole paper?

Comment: [link](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2600000/2594299/p259-arzt.pdf?ip=218.106.182.80&id=2594299&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=BF85BBA5741FDC6E%2E68C876273B0CA8EC%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&CFID=698057387&CFTOKEN=48437942&__acm__=1480292504_dd1b811c4e2dc25b6c0c16b25346bf2a)

Answer (score 0):

This is a data flow analysis algorithm. It provides a description what a program do. So, if 'n'-clause is assignment lhs = rhs (line 14), then it replaces rhs by lhs to show that the data is served by lhs variable.